# How to make filter using map in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to make some filter in javascript.
There is an array of riders and when ID of rider is inside of orders, it passes by filter.
I made this filter.

```
let riders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const orders = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 3 }, { Id: 1 }];

const ho = riders.filter((index) => {
  orders.map((order) => order.Id === index) === true;
});
```

And I want to get the result like

```
console.log(ho) // [1, 3]
```

But the result gives [ ].
How can I make this correctly using filter or map or other methods of array without for loop?

Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the IDs from `orders` using `map`, then use `filter` and `includes`. Also note that you're using `=> {` (block function notation), which doesn't implicitly return - so you need a `return` if you're using `=> {`, but don't if you use `=>`.

```js
let riders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const orders = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 3 }, { Id: 1 }];

const id = orders.map(({ Id }) => Id);

const ho = riders.filter(e => id.includes(e));

console.log(ho);
```

You could do it without the `id` array if you use `findIndex`:

```js
let riders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const orders = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 3 }, { Id: 1 }];

const ho = riders.filter(item => orders.findIndex(({ Id }) => item == Id) != -1);

console.log(ho);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and in callback check if the `Id` is present in riders. This `acc.indexOf(curr.Id) === -1` will prevent duplicate in accumulator array

```js
let riders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const orders = [{
  Id: 1
}, {
  Id: 3
}, {
  Id: 1
}];
const filter = orders.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (riders.includes(curr.Id) && acc.indexOf(curr.Id) === -1) {
    acc.push(curr.Id)
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce()` and a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store  the order ID's.

A Set only contains unique values and is a more efficient lookup object than an array

```js
const riders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    orders = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 3 }, { Id: 1 }],
    orderIds = orders.reduce((a,{Id})=> a.add(Id), new Set),
    ho = riders.filter(id => orderIds.has(id));
    
console.log(ho)
```